# How to run extension=mongo.so in php.ini

Tags: php, mongodb, centos

I am using centos 6. I have installed mongoDB using `yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server`. I started the mongo server using `/etc/init.d/mongod start`. I then added `extension=mongo.so` to my php.ini. I then restarted my apache server with `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`, and all are ok. but mongo php-driver is not working properly. when I checked my php version with `php version`, I got an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: version
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: do `ldd usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so` and see if there's no missing shared library this library depends on. Also check if the file really exists in above path

Comment: You need to build the PHP module for MongoDB yourself, did you do that step?  See [MongoDB Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.manual)

Comment: yeah i have done but no such file is found

Comment: i have mongodb-mongo-php-driver-1.3.0beta1-38-gf4f018e.zip file. now how can i install this driver in my server?

Comment: You need to follow the installation instructions located here: - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: To anyone who encounters this question in 2023+ keep in mind that the mongo.so extension is discontinued and does not work with new MongoDB versions. Please use the (confusingly) similarly named mongodb.so extension. The instructions to install that are in the duplicate question