# Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongo.so'

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, ubuntu-16.04

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library > '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongo.so' - > /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongo.so: cannot > open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

I am getting this weird error, i am working ubuntu 16.04
and i am new in ubuntu and mongo. I have searched a lot this error on google but i could not find any solution.

Kindly ignore the mistakes of mine, and try to provide a suitable solution.

thanks.

Comment: Looks like the mongo extension isn't installed. Have you tried `apt-get install php5-mongo`?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181280/how-to-run-extension-mongo-so-in-php-ini. Though this question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Hey @DaanMeijer i know its too late, but i have tried this command but no luck. It shows me an error  `E: Unable to locate package php7-mongo` (as i am using php v7)

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486808/installing-the-php-7-mongodb-client-driver

Comment: @DaanMeijer thank you so much, this link guided me to install the PECL Library, and to install it i used `sudo pecl install mongodb` this command installed all the needed extensions then i restarted my apache server and bingo, it worked like charm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing the PHP 7 MongoDB Client/Driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486808/installing-the-php-7-mongodb-client-driver)